# EntryCompletion: Message if no or too many matches

Tags: autocomplete, pygtk

I want to use EntryCompletion from pygtk[1].

I could not find a way to tell the user if there are no or too many matches.

Adding an extra gtk.Label would be possible, but does not look very nice. I guess other developer who use EntryCompletion want to display a message like "no matches found" to their users...

[1] http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkentrycompletion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were too many things which were not available in EntryCompletion. I use a Label and an Entry now. I connect to the "changed" event and update the label.